# How do I use protobuf deserialization in rows from a KSQLDB query?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, ksqldb

I'm trying to standardize deserialization in my KSQLDB app in Java but I'm struggling to understand how to handle the `Row` type returned by the KSQLDB `Client` type.  Ex (try/catches removed):

```java
    import io.confluent.ksql.api.client.Client;
    import io.confluent.ksql.api.client.BatchedQueryResult;

    Client ksqldbClient = kafkaService.getKSQLDBClient();
    String queryString = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = '%s';", tableName, primaryKeyName, id);
    BatchedQueryResult query = ksqldbClient.executeQuery(queryString);
    List<Row> rows = query.get();
```

My KSQLDB tables are configured to use protobuf serialization, but it seems like the `Row` type is a JSON?  I can only manage to get its data via:

```java
    for (Row row : rows) {
        String json = row.asObject().toJsonString();
        // Deserialize json string
        ...
    }
```

Does the KSQLDB client just handle the protobuf deserialization on its own?  Is there a way to get just the protobuf bytes so I can pass it into my Protobuf deserializer I have already defined so I don't need to also write a JSON deserializer?

Comment: It is already deserialized. You can get the specific fields from `row.asObject()`, for example, `getString`, `getDouble`, etc. Why would you want the bytes or a JSON string?

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying.  Feel free to post an answer with some examples to claim the rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row.asObject()` returns a KsqlObject which is already deserialized and operates similarly to a JDBC ResultSet in that you may call various get methods on it for the types within the row.

If you wanted to map to a specific domain object that you would have generated from Protobuf, there doesn't seem to be a direct way, and you'd likely be better off using Kafka Streams directly rather than KSQL if you needed that feature